# Finding the angle of rotation of an ellipse from its general equation and the other way around

Tags: conic-sections

The general equation for an ellipse is $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+D=0$. How do I find the angle of rotation, the dimensions, and the coordinates of the center of the ellipse from the general equation and vice versa? Please avoid using matrices or parametric equations. I'd like all-in-one equations for each parameter.

Comment: To get center, angle and axes lenghts from the general quadratic form you can find a very detailed explanation in *Information About Ellipses* by David Eberly at Geometric Tools, LLC.
See http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/InformationAboutEllipses.pdf

Answer (score 16):

The general equation of an ellipse is:
$$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$
if: 
$$4AC - B^2 > 0$$
The trick is to eliminate B so that the xy term vanishes.
If $B<>0$ then the ellipse is rotated and the angle of rotation is obtained from:
$$tan(2 \theta) = \frac {B}{A-C}$$ 
$0 < \theta < \frac {\pi}{4}$

$$\cos {\theta} = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos{2 \theta}}{2}}$$
$$\sin{\theta} = \sqrt{\frac{1 - cos{2 \theta}}{2}}$$
Determine the new equation of the ellipse by calculating the following coefficients:
$A' = A \cos^2{\theta} + B \cos{\theta} \sin{\theta} + C \sin^2{\theta}$
$B' = 0$
$C' = A \sin^2{\theta} - B \cos{\theta} \sin{\theta} + C \cos^2{\theta}$
$D' = D \cos{\theta} + E \sin{\theta}$
$E' = -D \sin{\theta} + E \cos{\theta}$
$F' = F$

The resulting equation: $A'x'^2 + C'y'^2 + D'x' + E'y' + F' = 0$
After writing this equation in the form: 
$$ \frac{(x'-x'_0)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y'-y'_0)^2}{b^2} = 1$$

We get:
$$x'_0 = \frac{-D'}{2A'}$$
$$y'_0 = \frac{-E'}{2C'}$$

$$a^2 = \frac{-4F'A'C'+C'D'^2+A'E'^2}{4A'^2C'}$$
$$b^2 = \frac{-4F'A'C'+C'D'^2+A'E'^2}{4A'C'^2}$$

The coordinates of the centerpoint are found by rotating back about angle $\theta$

$x_0 = x'_0 \cos{\theta} - y'_0 \sin{\theta}$
$y_0 = x'_0 \sin{\theta} + y'_0 \cos{\theta}$

Cheers!

Comment: The thing that is getting me with tan(2 * theta) = B / (A - C) is that I always get a result between 0 and pi/4 as you say. I was expecting a result between 0 and pi/2, because I want to know which of the axes (the major one or the minor one) is at the resulting angle, so that I can later draw it correctly.

Comment: Maybe http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html (eq. 23) gives an answer to that: if $a>c$, add $\pi/2$.

Comment: @JThemen What about *vice versa* of the question?

Comment: @TorstenBronger beware of  wolfram  - they write  the general quadratic as $ Ax^2 + 2Bxy + CY^2 + 2Dx + 2Ey + F $

Comment: Could you please quote the link showing the formula for theta? Wikipedia shows a much more involved formula, and I wonder why. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse

Comment: @DougMcClean, to obtain the correct angle one needs to use the ATAN2 function. In particular supposing that a is the major axis or semiaxis, the angle that it forms with the X axis is ATAN2( (C-A), -B) / 2. This formula will give you all possible angles, also those above 45 degrees up to 90, and those < -45, down to -90. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

The equation that you give is the equation of a general conic. Some of which are ellipses, some hyperbolae, some parabolae, and other degenerate conics, e.g. $xy=0$, $x^2=0$ or $x^2+y^2=0$.

The non-degenerate cases are distinguished by the way the conics interact with the line at infinity. We have:

1. If $B^2-4AC < 0$ then we have an ellipse; the conic misses the line at infinity.
2. If $B^2-4AC = 0$ then we have a parabola; the conic is tangent to the line at infinity.
3. If $B^2-4AC > 0$ then we have a hyperbola; the conic crosses the line at infinity twice.

The centre of a conic is foung by solving the equations $\partial f/\partial x = \partial f /\partial y = 0$ where $f(x,y)$ is the equation you gave. In this case, assuming $B^2-4AC \neq 0$, we have the centre $(p,q)$ as:

$$(p,q) = \left(\frac{2CD-BE}{B^2-4AC},\frac{2AE-DB}{B^2-4AC}\right) . $$

As for the rotation, assume you have either an ellipse or a hyperbola. You need to complete the square on the $x^2$ and $x$ terms, as well as the $y^2$ and $y$ terms. This is equivalent to translating the conic so that its centre is at the origin. You can then re-label $(x-p)$ as $X$ and $(y-q)$ as $Y$ and divide through by a constant to  give yourself a non-degenerate quadratic form, something like $aX^2+bXY + cY^2=1$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers. You then look at the matrix of the quadratic form:

$$Q = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & \frac{1}{2}b \\ \frac{1}{2}b & c \end{array}\right) . $$

The eigenvectors of $Q$ give you the axes of the conic. In order to rotate the matrix, you need to find an orthogonal change of basis matrix which diagonalises $Q$. Finally, you will end up with $\alpha X^2+\beta Y^2=1$.

**EXAMPLE**

Take the example $10x^2+12xy+10y^2=1$. The quadratic form on the left has matrix
$$M := \left(\begin{array}{cc} 10 & 6 \\ 6 & 10 \end{array}\right)$$
The eigenvectors of $M$ are $(1,1)^{\top}$ and $(1,-1)^{\top}$ with corresponding eigenvalues of $16$ and $4$ respectively. That gives $(1/\sqrt 2,1/\sqrt 2)^{\top}$ and $(1/\sqrt 2, -1/\sqrt 2)^{\top}$ as an orthogonal basis, i.e. unit length and perpendicular. Changing to this basis will diagonalise the quadratic form. (The change of basis will be a rotation.) If
$$V:=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1/\sqrt 2 & 1/\sqrt 2 \\ 1/\sqrt 2 & -1/\sqrt 2\end{array}\right) \ \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ \ D:=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 16 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \end{array}\right)$$
then $MV=VD$. The matrix $V$ is orthogonal, and so $V^{-1}=V^{\top}$ meaning that $D=V^{-1}MV=V^{\top}MV$. If $x = {x\choose y}$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^{\top}D x &=& x^{\top}V^{\top}MV x \\ \\
&=& (V x)^{\top}M(V x)
\end{eqnarray*}
A change of coordinates $x \mapsto Vx$ will diagonalise the quadratic form. If we put
\begin{eqnarray*}
x &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\,X + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\,Y \\ \\
y &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\, X - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\, Y
\end{eqnarray*}
then $10x^2+12xy+10y^2 \leadsto 16X^2 + 4Y^2$. Meaning that the locus $10x^2+12xy+10y^2=1$ can be rotated to the locus $16x^2+4y^2=1$, which is an ellipse crossing the $x$-axis at $\pm \frac{1}{4}$, and the $y$-axis at $\pm \frac{1}{2}$.

[image]

Comment: I do not know what eigenvectors are and I don't see how the matrix correlates to the description of the ellipse.

Comment: @Melab If you type "eigenvector" into Google then you will find many pages. An eigenvector of a matrix is a vector whose direction is fixed by that matrix, i.e. $Mv = \lambda v$ where $M$ is a matrix, $v$ is a vector and $\lambda$ is a number. As for the matrix, multiply the left by $(X,Y)$ and the right by $(X,Y)^{\top}$. What do you get? You get $aX^2+bXY+cY^2$.

Comment: @FlybyNight What about *vice versa* of the question?

Comment: Could you please explain the above concept with an example, such as $(10x^2 + 10y^2 + 12xy = 1)$.

Comment: @AnshKumar I've added an example to my post. Hope it helps. Please remember to upvote answer that you find useful.

Comment: The eigenvectors of the matrix $M$ gives us the axes of the conic but how would we know which one semi-major or semi-minor axis? Also, how to find the angle of rotation ?

Comment: @AnshKumar The semi-major is the longest and the semi-minor is the shortest.$\frac{1}{2}> \frac{1}{4}$. The rotation is given by $x \mapsto Vx$. Compare the matrix $V$ to the standard formula for a rotation, and solve for $\theta$:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos \theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1/\sqrt 2 & 1/\sqrt 2 \\ -1/\sqrt 2 & 1/\sqrt 2 \end{array}\right)$$

I get $\theta = -\frac{1}{4}\pi$ which gives a clockwise rotation of $45^{\circ}$.

Comment: @AnshKumar You're right that it is $45^{\circ}$, that was my mistake. Think of complex numbers: positive angles go anti-clockwise, so negative angles go clockwise. Your example could be rotated either way. Rotating clockwise by $45^{\circ}$ puts the semi-major axis along the $y$-axis and the semi-minor axis along the $x$-axis. Rotating anti-clockwise by $45^{\circ}$ puts the semi-major axis along the $x$-axis and the semi-minor axis along the $y$-axis. That would swap the $16$ and the $4$ in the matrix $D$, and would give $4x^2+16y^2=1$ instead of $16x^2+4y^2=1$. My choice was $16x^2+4y^2=1$.

Comment: @AnshKumar See the picture I've added for more details. The black curve is your original example $10x^2+12xy+10y^2=1$. The red curve is what you get by rotating clockwise (about the origin) by $45^{\circ}$.

Comment: Everything is now becoming clear to me. Could you tell me little bit about quadratic form of matrix and also why its eigenvectors are giving us axes of the conics ? A link to some reference might also be helpful.

Comment: @AnshKumar All of the explanation is already contained in the details of my answers, e.g. $MV=VD$, etc. Just go through the details and check it.

Comment: Isn't $(1/\sqrt 2,1/\sqrt 2)^{\top}$ and $(1/\sqrt 2, -1/\sqrt 2)^{\top}$ an **orthonormal** basis ?

Comment: +1 for the amazing answer. So, it's always the case that the eigenvalues become the coefficients of the nonrotated ellipse equation.

Answer (score 6):

$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx + Ey +F=0 \hspace{2 mm} .. (1)$ represents a general equation for conic. It includes a pair of straight line, circles, ellipse, parabola, and hyperbola. For this general equation to be an ellipse, we have [certain criteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant_classification).

Suppose this is an ellipse centered at some point $(x_0, y_0)$. Our usual ellipse  centered at this point is
$$\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2} = 1 \hspace{ 2 cm } (2)$$

Note that this term does not have $xy$ term. This term appears due to rotation. So let's us counter rotate it such that $xy$ term vanishes. We let $x = X \cos \theta  + Y \sin \theta$ and $y =   - X \sin \theta + Y \cos \theta $, we plug this into $(1)$ and equate the coefficient of $xy$ to $0$ since we assume that by rotation $(xy)$ vanishes. From here, we can calculate $\theta $. If it's an ellipse then we are be able to reduce the remnant of $(1)$ into the form $(2)$. Hence we find the center.

Comment: I learned how to rotate conics back in a course "calculus and analytic geometry" in the 1960s.  I observe that more recent textbooks tend not to include it.  It may (perhaps) be in linear algebra courses sometimes nowadays.

Comment: I do not really understand these transformation equations. GEdgar is right. I learned about ellipses in my trigonometry class and we only worked with ones aligned with axes.

Comment: it it [explained here](http://www.petesqbsite.com/sections/tutorials/tuts/relsoft3d/Chapter2/Chapter2.htm) , sorry i had been writing it oppositely. fixed it

Comment: What do $X$ and $Y$ equal?

Comment: They are the new coordinates after rotating in rotated coordinates. [This red](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Counterclockwise_rotation.png) line becomes new X-axis and it's perpendicular new Y-axis

Comment: @SantoshLinkha What about *vice versa* of the question?

Answer (score 5):

For the vice versa part of the question: the parameterization for the ellipse centered at the origin and with semi major axis equal to $a$ (parallel to the frame of reference) and semi minor axis equal to $b$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a\cos\varphi\\b\sin\varphi\end{pmatrix}\qquad\varphi\in[0,2\pi)$$

If I rotate the ellipse of the angle $\theta$ with the rotation matrix $R=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$ I will get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}a\cos\varphi\\b\sin\varphi\end{pmatrix}$$

If I translate the center from $(0,0)$ to $(x_c,y_c)$ I will get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}a\cos\varphi\\b\sin\varphi\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}x_c\\y_c\end{pmatrix}$$

Now I would like to isolate $\cos\varphi$ and $\sin\varphi$, then square them and finally get the quadratic form.

$$\begin{pmatrix}x-x_c\\y-y_c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}a\cos\varphi\\b\sin\varphi\end{pmatrix}$$

Since $R$ is a rotation matrix, it holds $R^{-1}=R^T$ and so I can multiply both sides by $R^T$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x-x_c\\y-y_c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a\cos\varphi\\b\sin\varphi\end{pmatrix}$$

Now I do the matrix vector product:

$$\cos(\theta)(x-x_c)+\sin(\theta)(y-y_c)=a\cos\varphi$$

$$-\sin(\theta)(x-x_c)+\cos(\theta)(y-y_c)=b\sin\varphi$$

and I isolate $\cos\varphi$ and $\sin\varphi$:

$$\frac{\cos(\theta)(x-x_c)+\sin(\theta)(y-y_c)}{a}=\cos\varphi$$

$$\frac{-\sin(\theta)(x-x_c)+\cos(\theta)(y-y_c)}{b}=\sin\varphi$$

Now, since $\cos^2\varphi+\sin^2\varphi=1$, I get

$$\left(\frac{\cos(\theta)(x-x_c)+\sin(\theta)(y-y_c)}{a}\right)^2+
\left(\frac{\cos(\theta)(y-y_c)-\sin(\theta)(x-x_c)}{b}\right)^2=1$$

I will now use [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to extract the coefficients $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$ of the quadratic form $$Ax^2 + By^2 + Cxy + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$

```
from sympy import *
theta,x_c,y_c,a,b,x,y=symbols('theta x_c y_c a b x y')
exp_1=((cos(theta)*(x-x_c)+sin(theta)*(y-y_c))/a)**2+((cos(theta)*(y-y_c)-sin(theta)*(x-x_c))/b)**2-1
exp_2=expand(exp_1)
P=poly(exp_2,x,y)
A,B,C,D,E,F=symbols('A B C D E F')
A_=P.coeff_monomial(x**2)
B_=P.coeff_monomial(y**2)
C_=P.coeff_monomial(x*y)
D_=P.coeff_monomial(x)
E_=P.coeff_monomial(y)
F_=P.coeff_monomial(1)
print(latex(relational.Eq(A, A_)))
print(latex(relational.Eq(B, B_)))
print(latex(relational.Eq(C, C_)))
print(latex(relational.Eq(D, D_)))
print(latex(relational.Eq(E, E_)))
print(latex(relational.Eq(F, F_)))
```

$$A = \frac{1}{b^{2}} \sin^{2}{\left (\theta \right )} + \frac{1}{a^{2}} \cos^{2}{\left (\theta \right )}$$
$$B = \frac{1}{b^{2}} \cos^{2}{\left (\theta \right )} + \frac{1}{a^{2}} \sin^{2}{\left (\theta \right )}$$
$$C = - \frac{2}{b^{2}} \sin{\left (\theta \right )} \cos{\left (\theta \right )} + \frac{2}{a^{2}} \sin{\left (\theta \right )} \cos{\left (\theta \right )}$$
$$D = - \frac{2 x_{c}}{b^{2}} \sin^{2}{\left (\theta \right )} + \frac{2 y_{c}}{b^{2}} \sin{\left (\theta \right )} \cos{\left (\theta \right )} - \frac{2 x_{c}}{a^{2}} \cos^{2}{\left (\theta \right )} - \frac{2 y_{c}}{a^{2}} \sin{\left (\theta \right )} \cos{\left (\theta \right )}$$
$$E = \frac{2 x_{c}}{b^{2}} \sin{\left (\theta \right )} \cos{\left (\theta \right )} - \frac{2 y_{c}}{b^{2}} \cos^{2}{\left (\theta \right )} - \frac{2 x_{c}}{a^{2}} \sin{\left (\theta \right )} \cos{\left (\theta \right )} - \frac{2 y_{c}}{a^{2}} \sin^{2}{\left (\theta \right )}$$
$$F = -1 + \frac{x_{c}^{2}}{b^{2}} \sin^{2}{\left (\theta \right )} - \frac{2 x_{c}}{b^{2}} y_{c} \sin{\left (\theta \right )} \cos{\left (\theta \right )} + \frac{y_{c}^{2}}{b^{2}} \cos^{2}{\left (\theta \right )} + \frac{x_{c}^{2}}{a^{2}} \cos^{2}{\left (\theta \right )} + \frac{2 x_{c}}{a^{2}} y_{c} \sin{\left (\theta \right )} \cos{\left (\theta \right )} + \frac{y_{c}^{2}}{a^{2}} \sin^{2}{\left (\theta \right )}$$

Inspired by [Compute center, axes and rotation from equation of ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1217796/10799)

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse

Comment: This is good work. I wanna ask what is the following formula called? Is it called canonical form of the rotated and translated ellipse? $$\left(\frac{\cos(\theta)(x-x_c)+\sin(\theta)(y-y_c)}{a}\right)^2+
\left(\frac{\cos(\theta)(y-y_c)-\sin(\theta)(x-x_c)}{b}\right)^2=1$$

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER I am sorry, I do not know.