# How to find the line through the major axis of an ellipse

Tags: geometry

Suppose for example an ellipse $x^2-2xy+2y^2=2$. How can we find the equation of the line through its major axis?

Another question on its area is possibly easy.

Comment: Consider rotation of axes

Comment: @Shailesh You will find it is quite hard to orthogonalize $A$.

Comment: See if [this](http://www.maa.org/external_archive/joma/Volume8/Kalman/QuadForm.html) helps or our own SE site see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280937/finding-the-angle-of-rotation-of-an-ellipse-from-its-general-equation-and-the-ot)

Comment: This is the equation rotated through $\frac{\pi}{8}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ellipse is obviously centered at the origin, and the axis are of the form $y=mx$.

Substituting in the ellipse equation,

$$x^2-2mx^2+2m^2x^2=2$$ you get the intersection points

$$(x,y)=\pm\left(\frac2{\sqrt{1-2m+2m^2}},\frac{2m}{\sqrt{1-2m+2m^2}}\right).$$

The squared distance to the center is
$$4\frac{1+m^2}{1-2m+2m^2}.$$

By cancelling the derivative, you find two solutions,

$$-\phi,\phi^{-1}$$ where $\phi$ is the Golden section. (Note that the product is $-1$, as should be.)

The corresponding squared distances (i.e. semi-axis lengths) are 
$$4\phi^{-2},4\phi^2.$$

Comment: Caution: this is a do-it-yourself solution, probably not the one expected by the teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Change to orthogonal co-ordinate axes whose equations in $x,y$  are $y=x\tan W$ and $y=x\cot W$  with $W$ to be determined.So $x=u\cos W + v\in W$ and $y=-u\sin  W +v \cos W$ .  Substitute into the equation for the ellipse and put the co-efficient of $u v$ to be $0$. This imposes a condition of the form $ 2 A\sin W \cos W =B(\cos^2 W-\sin^2 W)$, that is, $A\sin 2 W=B \cos 2 W$. Solve for $W$. The major axis of the ellipse, in terms of $x,y$ is on the line $y=x \tan W$.The equation of the ellipse ,in terms of $u,v$ is of the form $Cu^2+Dv^2=E$ with positive $C.D.E$, from which the area is readily found.