# Finding the parameters of an ellipsoid given its quadratic form

Tags: conic-sections, 3d, quadratic-forms

Suppose we have the quadratic form of an ellipsoid of the form

$$ax^2 + by^2+cz^2+dxy+eyz+fxz+gx+hy+iz+j=0$$

I want to find centroid of the arbitrarily oriented ellipsoid, its semi-axes, and the angles of rotation.

For the 2D case I found an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280937/finding-the-angle-of-rotation-of-an-ellipse-from-its-general-equation-and-the-ot). I was wondering if someone can help me do the same for 3D.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! How much linear algebra have you seen? Particularly, do you know how to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a $3 \times 3$ real symmetric matrix?

Comment: Yes, I know that eigenvalues and eigenvectors define the length and direction of semi axes. However I do not get the right results.

Comment: You should probably include an example that did not work out well. If you have not tried any examples and are just hoping to do everything with variables, well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation of an ellipsoid centered at the origin has the form $q_A(\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{v}^T A \mathbf{v} = C$ where $C > 0$ and $A$ is a symmetric matrix whose eigenvalues are all positive. If the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_i$ with a corresponding orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $v_i$ (so $Av_i = \lambda_i v_i$) then the semi-principal axes of the ellipsoid are the $v_i$'s with lengths $\lambda_i$.

If the ellipsoid is centered at $\mathbf{p}$ instead of the origin, the equation describing it is

$$ q_A(\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{p}) = (\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{p})^T A (\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{p}) = \mathbf{v}^T A \mathbf{v} - 2 \mathbf{v}^T A \mathbf{p} + \mathbf{p}^T A \mathbf{p} = C.$$

Thus, the first part of the equation is quadratic in $\mathbf{v}$, the second part of the equation is linear in $\mathbf{v}$ and the third part is constant. To rewrite your equation in the form above, we set

$$ \mathbf{v} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}, A = \begin{pmatrix} a & \frac{d}{2} & \frac{f}{2} \\ 
\frac{d}{2} & b & \frac{e}{2} \\
\frac{f}{2} & \frac{e}{2} & c\end{pmatrix}, \mathbf{p} = A^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{-g}{2} \\ \frac{-h}{2} \\ \frac{-i}{2} \end{pmatrix}, C = \mathbf{p}^T A \mathbf{p} - j.$$

If the eigenvalues of $A$ are all positive and $C > 0$, then your equation indeed describes an ellipsoid whose center is $\mathbf{p}$ and whose semi-principal axes are given by an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$ with lengths the corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: Is the ellipse in your example assumed to be non-oriented? Because  I have calculated the center point $p$ the same way, but my actual question is how it can be determined in the oriented case.

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan What do you mean by "oriented"?

Comment: by oriented I mean that ellipsoid can be in general rotated about x,y or z axes. The direction of axes of ellipsoid is not the same direction of coordinate system axes.

Comment: Yes, this equation takes it into account.