# Matrix of the quadratic form

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, conic-sections, quadratic-forms

I was solving the following question,

> Let $P = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 1\\1 & 3\end{bmatrix}$. Consider the set $S$
>   of all vectors $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ such that 
>   $a^2 + b^2 = 1$ where $\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = P \begin{pmatrix}x \\y \end{pmatrix}$. Then $S$ is
>
> 1. a circle of radius $\sqrt{10}$
> 2. a circle of radius $\frac{1}{ \sqrt{10}}$
> 3. an ellipse with major axis along $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\1 \end{pmatrix}$
> 4. an ellipse with minor axis along $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\1 \end{pmatrix}$

On using the above conditions I'm getting the following equation
$$ 10x^2 + 10y^2 + 12xy = 1 $$
which is equation of an ellipse, but I'm unable to get it's major and minor axises. I referred the answer given by "Fly by Night" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/280956). He is saying to look at the matrix of quadratic form 
which I'm getting
$$Q = \begin{bmatrix}10 & 6\\6 & 10\end{bmatrix}$$
with eigenvectors $v_1 = (1,1)$ and $v_2 = (-1, 1)$
Now, these two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ should be the axis of conic. Now the model matrix which diagonalizes $Q$ is simply the eigen vector matrix, so the model matri $P = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

So, my question is how is the above procedure giving me angle of rotation of ellipse? And of course answer to my question which by the way if option (4). Quadratic form of matrix was not in my university syllabus so I'm finding it difficult to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to search for [Conics' Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections#Classification) by means of linear algebra, and/or you can also try what is written in one of the answers in the link you post:

$$\begin{cases}x=X\cos\theta+Y\sin\theta\\{}\\y=-X\sin\theta+Y\cos\theta\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{so substituting we get:}$$

$$10x^2+12xy+10y^2=1\rightarrow 10\left(X^2\cos^2\theta+XY\sin2\theta+Y^2\sin^2\theta+X^2\cos^2\theta-XY\sin2\theta+Y^2\sin^2\theta\right)+$$

$$+12\left((Y^2-X^2)\cos\theta\sin\theta+XY\cos2\theta\right)=1\iff$$

$$20\left(X^2\cos^2\theta+Y^2\sin^2\theta\right)+12\left((Y^2-X^2)\cos\theta\sin\theta+XY\cos2\theta\right)=1$$

Equating the $\;xy\;$ term to zero (as we'd like it to vanish...) we get

$$\cos2\theta=0\iff\theta=\frac\pi4+k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

so we can choose the basic angle $\;\theta=\frac\pi4\;$ , and get the equation:

$$10(X^2+Y^2)+6(Y^2-X^2)=1\iff 4X^2+16Y^2=1\iff\frac{X^2}{\left(\frac12\right)^2}+\frac{Y^2}{\left(\frac14\right)^2}=1$$

and thus this is clearly an ellipse, and in order to get the radiuses of the *original ellipse* just "go back" rotatinע $\;\frac\pi4\;$ **in the clockwise direction**, so the minor axis (the vertical one, of length $\;\frac14\;$ , as shown above) alines with the line with a slope of $\;\frac\pi4\;$ with the positive direction of the $\;x\,$ axis, meaning the line $\;y=x\;$ , giving you (4) as the correct option.

Comment: Actually I want to try the method specified by "Fly by Night" which uses matrix of quadratic form.

Comment: @AnshKumar But that's what you showed already in your question.... Why it works by means of linear algebra requires...well, knowledge of linear algebra, eigenvectors, eigenvalues and etc.

Comment: I just followed the steps in the link but I'm no able to interpret what I have got and what actually I did. So, I want to understand the meaning of each steps.

Comment: @AnshKumar For that I direct you to some link talking about classification of conics as this would be way to long to expose here, at least for me.

Comment: In the link it is written "The rotation by angle $\alpha$ can be carried out by diagonalizing the matrix $A_{33}$". What does it mean ?

Comment: @AnshKumar Yes, because we have a **symmetric matrix** which is *orthogonally diagonalizable*, meaning there's an **orthogonal** matrix (a rotation matrix) $\;P\;$ such that $\;P^{-1}AP=D=$ a diagonal matrix, with the eigenvalues of $\;A\;$ on the main diagonal. Have you studied this stuff in linear algebra?

Comment: I have studied that. But I'm unable to link matrix to geometry. Basically how these diagonal matrix and model matrices giving me major and minor axes and rotation ? I'm unable to visualize it.

Comment: @AnshKumar I think you'll need to complete this with a tutor and/or with a book(s): an orthogonal matrix is of the form $$P=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$  This is the reason we choose $\;X,\,Y\;$ in my answer the way we do. The above is a *rotation* in an$\;\theta\;$ counter clockwise...Try to prove this geometrically: it is simple.