# How to parametrize the ellipse $4x^2+\frac{y^2}9+xy=36$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections, parametrization

I know how to parametrize an ellipse that looks like $4x^2+\dfrac{y^2}9=36$ by using polar coordinates:$$2x=6\cos t\Longrightarrow x=3\cos t\\\frac y3=6\sin t\Longrightarrow y=18\sin t$$
But can someone explain how would I go about parametrizing the following ellipse?
$$4x^2 + \frac{y^2}9 + xy = 36$$
Can I use polar coordinates?

Comment: The idea would be to convert that ellipse into a "standard form" one, that is, one that looks something like $a^2(Ax + By)^2 + b^2(Bx - Ay)^2 = 1$ with $A^2 + B^2 = 1$. After that, you solve for the centre $(x_0, y_0)$ and parameterise as earlier.

Comment: $\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}$Let $f(x,y)=4x^2+xy + \frac{y^2}{9}$, then $f(x,y) = \x^T A \x$ where $\x = \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix}4 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/9\end{bmatrix}$. You can then diagonalise $A$ and go from there. You can find an example at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280937/finding-the-angle-of-rotation-of-an-ellipse-from-its-general-equation-and-the-ot.

Comment: Be warned that parameter $t$ in your equations is NOT the angle of polar coordinates.

Comment: What sort of parameterization would you like? There are many possibilities.

Comment: Beware, the standard form route leads to the parametrization $$x= \frac{81
 \,2^{\frac{3}{2}}\,\sin t}{\sqrt{2612-70\,\sqrt{1306}}\,\sqrt{
 \sqrt{1306}+37}}+\frac{81\,2^{\frac{3}{2}}\,\cos t}{\sqrt{37-
 \sqrt{1306}}\,\sqrt{70\,\sqrt{1306}+2612}}$$


$$y=\frac{9\,2^{\frac{
 3}{2}}\,\left(\sqrt{1306}-35\right)\,\sin t}{\sqrt{2612-70\,
 \sqrt{1306}}\,\sqrt{\sqrt{1306}+37}}-\frac{9\,2^{\frac{3}{2}}\,
 \left(\sqrt{1306}+35\right)\,\cos t}{\sqrt{37-\sqrt{1306}}\,
 \sqrt{70\,\sqrt{1306}+2612}} 
 $$

Answer (score 2):

You can "complete the square". First of all rewrite your equation without denominators:
$$
36x^2+9xy+y^2=18^2,
$$
then observe that
$$
36x^2+9xy+y^2=\left({9\over2}x+y\right)^2+\left(36-{81\over4}\right)x^2=
\left({9\over2}x+y\right)^2+\left({3\sqrt7\over2} x\right)^2.
$$
Hence you can rewrite your equation as:
$$
\left({9\over2}x+y\right)^2+\left({3\sqrt7\over2} x\right)^2=18^2
$$
and a possible parametrisation is thus:
$$
{3\sqrt7\over2} x = 18\cos t \implies x={12\over\sqrt7}\cos t\\
{9\over2}x+y = 18\sin t \implies y=18\sin t-{54\over\sqrt7}\cos t.
$$